# Removing empty footnote space

Tags: latex

I am using the ACM SIG Proceedings Templates, Option 1: LaTeX2e - Strict Adherence to SIGS style. I have no footnote but still the text column does not go to the end of the page. There is still empty space for footnote. How can I remove the empty space and make the text column go up to the end of the page ?

Comment: Could you just mock up a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) so the community can have something to work with?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because the ACM wants you to use it this way. Publications are very strict in terms of what you can/cannot do, so my first suggestion would be to *not change this*. The space left on the bottom of the first column on the first page is reserved for a copyright notice:

[image]

...however, if you want to remove it, add

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\makeatletter
% \patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
\patchcmd{\maketitle}{\@copyrightspace}{}{}{}
\makeatother
```

to the document preamble. This patch (thanks to [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox)) removes `\@copyrightspace` from `\maketitle`. The result look like this:

[image]